# Does java define string as null terminated?

Tags: java, string, null

As my title suggests, it's a theoretical question. I'd like to know that if java defines string as null terminated.

Comment: @Reimeus, so how they track string ending? Using length?

Comment: Didn't see that question although searched google before. May be a duplicate!

Comment: Dewsworld, stating it's a theoretical question is almost a dead-cert reason for closing. SO is supposed to be for actual problems that you face.

Comment: @MatteoD - That question is actually about something different.  It has a misleading title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java strings are not terminated with a null characters as in C or C++. Although java strings uses internally the char array but there is no terminating null in that. String class provides a method called length to know the number of characters in the string.

Here is the simple code and its debugger contents:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Juned";
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Debugger screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reasoning to support your answer?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan, Can you please explain a little :)

Comment: The java specification does not mention it but if you run your code in debug mode, you can alaways see the contents of String internal array, and there will be no terminating null character.

Comment: Java is the JLS, which doesn't mandate null-termination but doesn't _disallow_ it either. The fact that one _implementation_ of Java doesn't do it is less relevant than you think. I won't vote you down but you _may_ want to make the distinction between the Java specification and implementations.

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the screenshot?

Comment: @Josh, it's likely to be the fact that there's no `[5] = '\0'` line in `s.value`.

Comment: This implementation (`char[] value; int offset, count;`) was dropped around 7u6, about a year before this answer was posted. Since then the length of the array `value` is used as the length of the String (all Java arrays, of any type, maintain their own length). Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368741/why-is-string-class-in-java-implemented-using-char-offset-and-length

Answer (score 14):

> I'd like to know that if java defines string as null terminated.

No.  A String is defined to be a fixed length sequence of `char` values.  All possible `char` values (from 0 to 65535) may be used in a String.  There is no "distinguished" value that means that the string ends<sup>1</sup>.

> So how they track string ending? Using length?

Yes.  A `String` object has a private `length` field (in all implementations I've examined ...).

If you want to understand more about how Java strings are implemented, the source code for various versions is available online.  Google for "java.lang.String source".

---

<sup>1 - As noted, neither the JLS or the javadocs for `String` specifically that a `String` implementation cannot use NUL termination.  However, the fact that all characters including NUL are significant in a `String` means that NUL termination is not practical.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter?

If you convert a Java string into some kind of serialized format (onto disk, the network, etc.), then all that matters is the serialization format, not the JVM's internal format.

If you're reading the string's data in C code via JNI, then you never read the data directly, you always use JNI functions like [`GetStringChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17158) or `GetStringUTFChars()`.  `GetStringChars()` is not documented as returning null-terminated data, so you shouldn't assume that it's null-terminated—you must use `GetStringLength()` to determine its length.  Likewise with `GetStringUTFChars()`, you must use `GetStringUTF8Length()` to determine its length in [modified UTF-8 format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16542).

Comment: "Does it matter?" Umm... it's nice to know how computers work.

Comment: It does matter if you are worried about what happens if you put a `NUL` character into a `String`.  However, if you are doing that, it is arguable that you are using `String` incorrectly ... because a `NUL` character should not appear in *real* text.  (But I accept that there are use-cases where you would want to allow `NUL` in a `String` anyway.)

Comment: It does matter: Today I was assuming that they were NUL terminated, and escaped a \0 in the middle of a string just to test a reverse() function, then reversed; and to my surprise, it reversed it even after the \0, so I came here to see why :)

Comment: Adam, although you've made your point pretty clear, you you didn't answer the question.  Upvoted it because you called our attention to an interesting issue in a provocative way.