# Remove the duplicate characters in a string

Tags: java, arrays

This is from cracking the Coding Interview Book.

> Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string 
>   without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine.
>   An extra copy of the array is not.

In the book it says time complexity is $O(N^2)$. How can we tell that the time complexity is $O(N^2)$ from the solution? 
I have questions as to how the solution is removing duplicate characters. I have included them in the inline comments below.

```
   public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
      if (str == null) return; // if the array is empty return  nothing?
      int len = str.length; // get the length of the array 
      if (len < 2) return; // if the array length is only 1 return nothing?
      int tail = 1; // initialise tail variable as 1 ! 
      // Why are we starting at second character here (at i = 1),why not start at i = 0 ? 
      for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) { 
        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < tail; ++j) { // so are we checking if j is less then 1 as tail has been initialized to 1 
          if (str[i] == str[j]) break; // stop, if we find duplicate.
        }

        if (j == tail) { why are we comparing j to tail(1) here ?
          str[tail] = str[i]; // assigning the value 
          ++tail; // incrementing tail
        }
      }
      str[tail] = 0; //setting last element as 0 
    }


 -
```

Comment: You say this method is in a book? It doesn't work. I tried `char[] arr = {'a','b','a','b'};removeDuplicates(arr);System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` and the output was `[a, b,  , b]`.

Comment: Is the order in which the characters appear in the string matters? If not, then simply apply `QuickSort`, on the given array, to sort each element of the array. This will have `O ( n log n )` complexity. Then simply iterate over the array ( complexity `O ( n )` ), and store only those characters, which you are encountering the first time, since every element is in increasing order, say `a, b, b, c, c, c, d`, simply start from `index = 1`, check if this value is equal to value at `compareWith = index - 1`. If they not equal append it to some variable, this way you will get unique occurrences

Comment: The code is correct, but this is pseudo code, no one said, it's Java. In java, the 0 is not terminating the string. In C the 0 or '\0' is terminating the string.
@pbabcdefp Your output is the correct answer, if you stop reading the string at the empty character.

Comment: @AdamOcsvari Oh I see, so the OP has tried to translate some pseudocode into Java and got it wrong. Fair enough.

Comment: Note though, that his question doesn't concern the logic.  The Big-O doesn't really care if it accomplishes a particular task or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completly rely on @pbabcdefp comment as I'm to lazy to test it, but it seems like your algorithm does not work.

I did not like it anyway, here how I would do it with explanation in comments :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    removeDuplicates(new char[]{'a','a','b','b','c','d','c'});
}

public static final void removeDuplicates(char[] str)
{
    /*
     * If the str is not instantiated, or there is maximum 1 char there is no need to remove duplicates as 
     * it is just impossible to have duplicate with 1 char.
    */
    if (str == null || str.length < 2)
        return;

    //loop over each char
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        //no need to check with earlier character as they were already checked, so we start at i + 1
        for(int j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++)
        {
            //if they match we clear
             if(str[j] == str[i])
                str[j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

That would output `a b cd`.

Comment: This is a wrong solution! You can argue that the task wasn't enough well defined, but if I want to remove the duplication from a string, it doesn't mean, replace the duplication in the string with some other characters.
If you need to remove, that means the string is shorter. If I have 1000 'a' character, then at the end I want to have only 1 character long string.

Comment: @AdamOcsvari I know that, I was just giving the algorithm to identify the duplicate characters. This is what I most of the time answer, I don't like spoon-feeding. I believe that from here OP should be able to understand the questions he asked.

Comment: How does re-writing his logic address his question?

How is this not spoon-feeding?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a great book, I wish to recommend to everyone!

Generally if you are allowed to use a lots of memory, you can save time, if you are allowed to use a few variables, then you still can solve this problem by a slower algorithm. And there is the complete brute-force algorithm, when you check every possible solution.

```
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
  if (str == null) return; // if the array is empty return  nothing?
```

The input is a string pointer, so the string exists somewhere in the memory, the code will may modify it, but it stays at the same place. That's why the return type of the function is void, so it doesn't return anything. When it returns, the string at its original place is without duplication.

```
  int len = str.length; // get the length of the array 
  if (len < 2) return; // if the array length is only 1 return nothing?
```

Same as above, no return value. If the string is less then 2 character, then it cannot contain a duplication.

From here the logic is the following:
Take the i-th character. Check if it was existing before this place in the string. If it exists, then the algorithm deletes the i-th character. If it doesn't exists then it stays in the string.

The proof that it's the right algorithm:
None of the characters will stay which existed earlier in the string. If a character would exists later in the string, it would be deleted because of the previous rule.

If this would be the algorithm, it would work fine, but there would be "Empty" characters in the string. The string wouldn't be smaller, even tough it should contain less characters.

That's why the algorithm keeps track on the "tail of the output string". That's why the tail is equals 1 at the beginning, since the 1st character will be definitely part of the result string.
When the current character should be deleted, the output string's tail wont move, no new character added to the result. When the current character should be part of the result, then it gets copied to the tail of the result string.

When the algorithm reaches the end of the input string, it closes the result string.

Complexity:
It means, relative to the size of the input, which is called 'n' how many steps the algorithm has to take. Typically cycles and recursions counts only.
This code has 2 for loop embedded into each other.
The external goes from 1 to n every time.
The internal one goes from 0 to tail where tail goes from 1 to n. So the worst case scenario, the internal one goes by average from 1 to n/2.
This means your complexity is n*(n/2). Since 2 is a constant, your complexity is n*n.

Comment: "None of the characters will stay which existed earlier in the string." Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I didn't tried to run a pseudo code. But I can see, why you get the wrong answer on java.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414873/does-java-define-string-as-null-terminated

Answer (score 2):

The O time complexity is about worst-case. Ignoring the array you get and the actions you do on it, when you have 2 nested for loops bounded by the length of the string, your complexity couldn't be higher than n^2, and thus it is O(n^2) (it is only an upper bound, if you'd like to show that it's also a lower bound more work should be done).

Comment: Generally you are right, but lets agree on that 2 loop doesn't mean your maximum complexity is O(n^2). You may have recursion or tricky modifications on the loop variable inside the loop. Or even with one loop, you can have an endless loop.

Comment: Recursion changes the game a bit, but without it, I believe the string length bound is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

O(N^2) basically means that as the number of inputs increases, N being the number of inputs, the complexity (number of operations performed) will scale porportional to N^2 + some constant value.

So looking at the code, str.length is N.  For each element, you compare it to each other element, N compared N times = N^2.

Now O(N^2) is not meant to be exact.  By definition it is concerned with only the non-constant factors that contribute to complexity growth.  It will never tell you how quickly a particular algorithm will run, it purely tells you how the time it takes to run will scale with fluctuations in the number of elements being operated on.

Answer (score 0):

### Use this for remove every duplicate lowercase

```
static boolean contains(char c, char[] array) {
    for (char x : array) {
        if (x == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s = "stackoverflow11221113" ;

String result = "";
for(char ch:s.toCharArray()){
  if(!contains(ch,result.toCharArray())){
    result +=ch;
  }
}
System.out.println(result);
}
```

### Use this for remove every duplicated character both lowercase or uppercase

```
static boolean contains(char c, char[] array) {
    for (char x : array) {
        if (x == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s = "StackOverFlow11221113" ;
String result = "";
for(char ch:s.toCharArray()){
  if(!contains(ch,result.toLowerCase().toCharArray())){
    result +=ch;
  }
}
System.out.println(result);
}
```