# Removing duplicates from sorted Char array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, character-arrays

I am trying to take the string below, convert it to an array, sort the array, then take out any duplicates. I have gotten to the sorted part, but when I run this in hopes for the duplicates being removed, it seems to print position instead of the value there.

This is also counting spaces as length, giving me a length of 59 for this.

Can I get some help figuring out what I need to change?
Thank you all!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Challenge208 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String numbers = "3 1 3 4 4 1 4 5 2 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 3 2 5 5 2 2 2 4 2 4 4 4 4 1";
    char[] chars = numbers.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    System.out.println(chars);

    int current = chars[0];
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (current == chars[i] && !found) {
            found = true;
        }else if (current != chars[i]) {
            System.out.print(" " + current);
            current = chars[i];
            found = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" " + current);

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573018/remove-the-duplicate-characters-in-a-string/29573068#29573068

Comment: Thank you! I still have one bug where my output has a TON of spaces. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Well this is a dirty fix, but since I have no idea what is your program, I believe `.trim()` method on a string instance would get rid of the un-needed spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`current` should be type `char` not `int`. To get rid of the spaces, you could print if `current` is not a space.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using array u can use treeset.. It will have a sorted order and no duplicates.. But if in your scenario you need array in that case first your current variable is int instead of char and you are not removing any of the duplicates.you are just printing that whenever you find that char even if that item does not have any duplicates and that only for char[0]

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the index of the number but its ascii value. For more details: http://www.asciitable.com/
But solution is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Challenge208 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String numbers = "3 1 3 4 4 1 4 5 2 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 3 2 5 5 2 2 2 4 2 4 4 4 4 1";
char[] chars = numbers.toCharArray();
char[] results = new char[10];
Arrays.sort(chars);
System.out.println(chars);

char current = chars[0];
int size = 0;
boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (current == chars[i] && !found) {
        found = true;
    }else if (current != chars[i]) {
        System.out.print(" " + current);
        size++;
        current = chars[i];
        found = false;
    }
}

System.out.print(" " + current);
System.out.print("\n"+size);

}
}
```

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, could you please mark it as the correct answer