# Why String class stores constants in char array instead of a String object

Tags: java, string, arrays

String class in JDK uses `private final char value[];` to store constants. I wonder why it does not use `private final String value`.

> Is there any reason related to performance or memory issues?

Comment: Are you suggesting `class String { private final String value; ... }`? Let that sink for a minute...

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368773/1974797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String class in jdk used private final char value[] ..

Here **used** means 'used to define the String class'. The writer of string class needed a container to store the value of the string, & while (s)he is still in process of writing String class, how can they use it?

e.g. While assembling a desktop, you don't start with a desktop itself - you start with some basic components like a CPU, screen, mouse, keyboard etc..

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class clearly can't use *itself* to store the value. (How would that work?)

It has to use *something else* to represent the string. That something else in an array of char.

Answer (score 0):

String class in JDK is used to declare the class : it appears obvious that the String class can't use itself to store a String.

Or maybe you think that String is a Java primitive ? Well, it's not !

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of [`String Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) itself

> **The String class represents character strings.**

So,if you not storing characters, Where does a String came :) ?

Comment: i can store the constants in a String object and use charAt(index) to iterate over it

Comment: `i can store the constants in a String object`, again where does the `String Object` came ? From characters right ?

Answer (score 0):

Think the String class as a wrapper for char[].

So the class uses char[] to store the effective value... it Can't use a String (as you said) because String doesn't exist without a place to store the characters.

In other words the chars are used for character storage as a primitive type and you can't do in a different way.